# How to get the value the foreign key represents MVC4

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

Currently, I have model which represents a table within my database.

```
public partial class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public string BookingFirstname { get; set; }
    public string BookingSurname { get; set; }
    public string BookingEmail { get; set; }
    public string BookingMobileTel { get; set; }
    public string BookingHomeTel { get; set; }
    public int BookingAge { get; set; }
    public int BookingPassengers { get; set; }
    public int DepartureId { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalId { get; set; }
}
```

DepartureId and ArrivalId are foreign keys of two other tables.

```
public partial class Departure
{
    public int DepartureId { get; set; }
    public string DepartureName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Arrival
{
    public int ArrivalId { get; set; }
    public int DepartureId { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to get the Arrival Name and Departure Name from the option selected when the user submits a form from the Book View.

This is currently the [HttpPost] Book Action Result:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Book(Booking bk)
    {
        List<Departure> departures = new List<Departure>();
        List<Arrival> arrivals = new List<Arrival>();

        using (BookingEntities db = new BookingEntities())
        {
            departures = db.Departures.OrderBy(a => a.DepartureName).ToList();
            if (bk != null && bk.DepartureId > 0)
            {
                arrivals = db.Arrivals.Where(a => a.DepartureId.Equals(bk.DepartureId)).OrderBy(a => a.ArrivalName).ToList();
            }
        }

        ViewBag.DepartureId = new SelectList(departures, "DepartureId", "DepartureName", bk.DepartureId);
        ViewBag.ArrivalId = new SelectList(arrivals, "ArrivalId", "ArrivalName", bk.ArrivalId);

        string emailTo = bk.BookingEmail;
        string emailBody = "Thank you for Booking with Callum Airways, " + bk.BookingFirstname + " " + bk.BookingSurname + ".\n" +
            "Here is confirmation that your booking was a success. We have listed the information you entered into this email.\n" +
            "Email: " + bk.BookingEmail + ",\n" +
            "Mobile Tel: " + bk.BookingMobileTel + ",\n" +
            "Home Tel: " + bk.BookingHomeTel + ",\n" +
            "Age: " + bk.BookingAge + ",\n" +
            "Number of Passengers: " + bk.BookingPassengers + ".\n\n" +
            // Departure and Arrival Names
            "If you want to review/delete your booking please register an account on ************.";


        // All the other booking information.

        using (BookingEntities db = new BookingEntities())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Bookings.Add(bk);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                bk = null;                    

                MailAddress from = new MailAddress("*************@gmail.com");
                MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailTo);
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                message.Subject = "Booking Confirmation - ********";
                message.Body = emailBody;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                smtp.Timeout = 10000;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********************", "*******");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(message);
            }              
        }
        return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", bk);
    }
```

I've been able to get the value of BookingFirstname and others but because there is just the foreign key not the name in the Booking Class. I'm not sure how I can get ArrivalName and DepartureName.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrival arrival = new Arrival();
arrival = db.Arrival.Where(w => w.ArrivalId.Equals(bk.ArrivalId).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.ArrivalName = arrival.ArrivalName; 

Departure departure = new Departure();
departure = db.Departure.Where(w => w.DeaId.Equals(bk.ArrivalId).FirstOrDefault();
ViewBag.DepartureName = departure.DepartureName;
```